# hbase - delete and put a field with same timestamp

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to delete a cell and add it using the same timestamp from hbase shell?

```
 delete 'BNM', '00347bbf5632aa0de0071a', 'PROCESS:TEST', 1374270908284
 put 'BNM', '00347bbf5632aa0de0071a', 'PROCESS:TEST', 'debug_prime1', 1374270908284
```

I am doing something like this, but the second put is not working.

Comment: how do you know the put is not working ?
i assume your using get. did you specify the timestamp in the get?
otherwise, i will return the latest version. which doesn't necessarily be the one that you just put.

Comment: Adding the timestamp on the get did not help.

Answer (score 4):

You will eventually see the result of put but it only be visible after major compaction on the table has happened. In general any put with timestamp <= delete timestamp and applied after delete will be visible only after major compaction has happened on the table.

Comment: It was not visible after major compaction.

Comment: You need to run the major compaction after the `delete`, but before the `put`. [Source] (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/28421)

Why do the `delete` at all? The `put` will replace whatever is there.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that Delete will trump Put when the timestamp is the same.
However, if a MJC happens before the Put, and some conditions are met (see conditions for removing Deletes on MJC in HBase book), then the Delete is discarded before it can affect the Put.